How to get provider if I am using rainbowkit wallet extension?
I am using window.ethereum to get the function for smart contract transaction but it only triggered my Metamask wallet extension instead of Rainbowkit. Is there an option to grab currently connected provider using wagmi?
  if (window.ethereum) {
    const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    await web3Provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', []); // Request user's wallet to connect
    const network = await web3Provider.getNetwork();
    if (network.chainId !== 80002) {
      setModalMessage('Please connect to the Polygon Amoy testnet');
      throw new Error('Please connect to the Polygon Amoy testnet');
    }
    const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
    const eventFactoryAddress = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EVENT_FACTORY_ADDRESS; // Use environment variable
    const eventFactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(eventFactoryAddress, EventFactory.abi, signer);
  
    setModalMessage(`Creating event "${formData.eventTitle}" on the blockchain...`);
  
    // Create the event on the blockchain with a higher gas limit
    let eventTransaction;
    try {
      eventTransaction = await eventFactoryContract.createEvent(
        formData.eventTitle,
        formData.eventSymbol,
        eventMetadataCID,
      );
    } catch (createError) {
      console.error('Error creating event transaction:', createError);
      setModalMessage(`Failed to create event transaction. Error: ${createError.message}`);
      setIsLoading(false);
      return;
    }
  
    const eventReceipt = await eventTransaction.wait();

Besides, below is my current setup for my _app.jsx, want to ask for advice from all. Thank you!
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'; 
import theme from '../styles/theme'; 
import Wrapper from '../layouts/Wrapper'; 
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'; 
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'; import '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/styles.css'; 
import {   getDefaultConfig,   RainbowKitProvider,   lightTheme, } from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit'; 
import { WagmiProvider } from 'wagmi'; 
import {   mainnet,   polygon,  optimism,   arbitrum,   base, } from 'wagmi/chains'; 
import {   webSocket } from '@wagmi/core'; 
import {   QueryClientProvider,   QueryClient, } from "@tanstack/react-query"; 
import {   RainbowKitSiweNextAuthProvider,   GetSiweMessageOptions, } from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit-siwe-next-auth'; 
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'; 
import NextNProgress from 'nextjs-progressbar';

// Define the SIWE message options const getSiweMessageOptions = () => ({   statement: 'Sign in to BlockSeats to organize events and purchase tickets.', });

const polygonAmoy = {   id: 80002,   name: 'Polygon Amoy Testnet',   network: 'polygon-amoy',   nativeCurrency: {
    name: 'MATIC',
    symbol: 'MATIC',
    decimals: 18,   },   rpcUrls: {
    default: 'https://rpc-amoy.polygon.technology/',   },   blockExplorers: {
    default: { name: 'Polygonscan', url: 'https://amoy.polygonscan.com/' },   },   testnet: true, };

const config = getDefaultConfig({   autoConnect: true,   appName: 'Welcome to my BlockSeats App',   projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_API_KEY, // Use the environment variable here   chains: [mainnet, polygon, optimism, arbitrum, base, polygonAmoy],   ssr: true, // If your dApp uses server side rendering (SSR)   transports: {
    [polygonAmoy.id]: webSocket(`wss://polygon-amoy.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`), // Your Alchemy WebSocket URL for polygonAmoy   }, });

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {   return (
    <WagmiProvider config={config}>
      <SessionProvider refetchInterval={0} session={pageProps.session}>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <RainbowKitSiweNextAuthProvider getSiweMessageOptions={getSiweMessageOptions}>
            <RainbowKitProvider
              coolMode
              theme={lightTheme()}
            >
              <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
                <Wrapper>
                  <NextNProgress/>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
                  <ToastContainer position="top-left" theme="dark" />
                </Wrapper>
              </ChakraProvider>
            </RainbowKitProvider>
          </RainbowKitSiweNextAuthProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </SessionProvider>
    </WagmiProvider>   ); }

export default MyApp;

